# How do I keep my own animated KDE wallpapers from running together?

Tags: c++, animation, wallpaper, kde-plasma

I recently tried writing animated wallpaper plugins for KDE4. When I switch among them, the animations get jumbled. That is, the previous animation doesn't stop, and the previous frames and the current frames get mixed together. I embed the frames into each program as image resources. Then I write code like the following for each wallpaper. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing (or if it's just a KDE bug)?

dancingcoffee.h

```
#ifndef DANCINGCOFFEE_H
#define DANCINGCOFFEE_H

#include <Plasma/Wallpaper>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>

class DancingCoffee : public Plasma::Wallpaper
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DancingCoffee(QObject *parent, const QVariantList& args);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &exposedRect);

private slots:
    void updateBackground();

    private:
    const int m_frames;
    const int m_interval;

    int m_frame_number;
    QTimer m_timer;
};

#endif // DANCINGCOFFEE_H
```

dancingcoffee.cpp

```
#include "dancingcoffee.h"
#include <QImage>

K_EXPORT_PLASMA_WALLPAPER(coffee, DancingCoffee)

DancingCoffee::DancingCoffee(QObject *parent, const QVariantList &args) :
    Plasma::Wallpaper(parent, args),
    m_frames(2),
    m_interval(1000 / m_frames)
{
    m_frame_number = 0;

    m_timer.setSingleShot(true);
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateBackground()));
    m_timer.start(m_interval);
}

void DancingCoffee::paint(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &exposedRect)
{
    QString name = QString(":/images/frame-%1.png").arg(m_frame_number);
    QImage image(name);
    painter->drawImage(exposedRect, image);
}

void DancingCoffee::updateBackground()
{
    ++m_frame_number;
    m_frame_number %= m_frames;
    m_timer.start(m_interval);
    emit update(boundingRect());
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)

project(plasma-wallpaper-coffee)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
find_package(KDE4Workspace REQUIRED)
include(KDE4Defaults)

add_definitions(${KDE4_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${KDE4_INCLUDES})

set(TARGET plasma_wallpaper_coffee)
set(SRC_LIST dancingcoffee.cpp)
qt4_add_resources(RCC_LIST dancingcoffee.qrc)

kde4_add_plugin(${TARGET} ${SRC_LIST} ${RCC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${KDE4_PLASMA_LIBS})

install(TARGETS ${TARGET} DESTINATION ${PLUGIN_INSTALL_DIR})
install(FILES plasma-wallpaper-coffee.desktop DESTINATION ${SERVICES_INSTALL_DIR})
```

plasma-wallpaper-coffee.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Coffee
Type=Service
Icon=image-jpeg
ServiceTypes=Plasma/Wallpaper

X-KDE-Library=plasma_wallpaper_coffee
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Author=Chris French
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Email=unclechromedome@gmail.com
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name=coffee
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Version=0.1
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Website=
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Depends=
X-KDE-PluginInfo-License=GPL
X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=true
```

And voila! Animated wallpaper on my desktop. But the wallpapers don't play well together. I have to kill the desktop and restart it when I switch wallpapers, and sometimes that doesn't even work. Sometimes I have to do a hard reboot. It's a pain for me, and unacceptable if I ever distribute the wallpapers.